# French Question regarding vector spaces

Tags: vector-spaces, translation-request, mathematical-french

I am not really sure how to translate "E spans F" into french. Could some of the french users assist me ?

Comment: Judging by the [article on vector spaces in French Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espace_vectoriel#Sous-espace_vectoriel_engendr.C3.A9), $E$ *engendre* $F$, and $F$ is *engendré par (la famille)* $E$.

Comment: I agree : "$E$ engendre $F$".

Comment: Remark: If we have a set $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ of vectors that spans a vector space $E$ then the symbolic translation of $E=\mathrm{span}(x_i)$ is $E=\mathrm{vect}(x_i)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*$E$ engendre $F$*, or, *la famille $E$ engendre $F$* and its declinations *$F$ est engendrée par $E$* or *l'espace vectoriel $F$ est engendré par $E$*.